# What is the maximum distance from an anchor point to a bezier curve?

Tags: geometry, distance, bezier

Given a cubic bezier curve P0,P1,P2,P3 with the following properties:

• Both P1 and P2 are on the same side of the line formed by P0 and P3.
• P2 can be projected onto the line segment formed by P0 and P3 but P1 cannot.

What is the T value for the point on the curve farthest from P3?

Here is an image with an [example curve](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/Bezier_3_big.gif/240px-Bezier_3_big.gif).  The curve bulges on the left, so there is a point on the curve farther from P3 than P0.

I found this reference for finding the [minimum distance](http://www.tinaja.com/glib/bezdist.pdf) from an arbitrary point to a curve.  Is trial and error the only way to solve for maximum distance as well?  Does it make any difference that the point is an anchor on the curve?

Thanks

Comment: This is more of a math problem than a programming problem. I wonder if it's too mundane for MathOverflow?

Comment: I went and looked around MathOverflow and felt a little out of my league.  I assume this is downright banal over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for a cubic Bezier curve is given in this [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).  Using simple calculus, you can find the formula for the tangent **B**'(t) of the curve at parameter t.

The farthest point of the curve from **P**<sub>3</sub> is characterized by the tangent **B**'(t) being perpendicular to the vector **B**(t)-**P**<sub>3</sub>.

So you need to find the value of t for which the dot product **B**'(t)⋅(**B**(t)-**P**<sub>3</sub>)=0.

Offhand, you're solving a quintic in t, so prepare to do some root finding.  I'd typically expect one root in the interval [0,1], but I suppose some configurations of the **P**<sub>i</sub> could have more than one root (in which case you select one that gives the largest distance).

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bound is easy to compute.. just the maximum distance to the convex hull.

If you're looking for a precise answer, then you'll have to do a search.